# margin best practise

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, margin

If I have a Horizontal StackPanel with many elements, with different margin between them:

Is there any difference if I give each element a left margin or 
is there some advantage giving every second element a right and left margin - that way only one element gets its margin property set.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Name="textblock1" />
<TextBlock Name="textblock2" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
<TextBlock Name="textblock3" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
...
</StackPanel>
```

or

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Name="textblock1" />
<TextBlock Name="textblock2" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
<TextBlock Name="textblock3" />
...
</StackPanel>
```

I was just wondering if there was a best-practise concerning this.

Comment: Margins are ugly in any case...

Comment: Coming from a web background I would chose the second because it's less to send over the wire. I'm not sure if it matters for WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Margin is the same for every element, you can factor it out in a style:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0" />
      </Style>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <TextBlock Name="textblock1" />
   <TextBlock Name="textblock2" />
   <TextBlock Name="textblock3" />
   ...
</StackPanel>
```

Other than that it makes no difference.

Comment: @H.B. Most questions are trivial if you're the right person to answer. Implicit styles in local resources is not considered trivial by most.

Comment: Well then I guess the answer is that It makes no difference like you said